# Is there a way to show a leader (such as dots) when using a Text(master, tabs()) or alternate in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Using Python 3.8 in Ubuntu 20.04

I have tried researching this but most of the time google thinks I am searching for Tabs on a document not tabs within a paragraph.

I need output as follows

"Toy Car ···················· $10.00"
"Toy Bear ···················· $5.00"

where the dots are tab leaders.  The font is not monospaced so I can not convert the text string and place them in manually.  Any ideas?

Thanks - Thomas

Comment: It would be very easy if you just used a monospaced font for the tables in your Text widget. Using tabs, you can ensure that only the tables are monospaced while any text between tables is normal. I use that in my programs where I have to display tables. Alternatively, you might try Treeview widgets that have fixed columns.

Comment: You can try using a `\u2024` character but `tkinter` doesn't render it correctly for me. According to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=leader+dot+unicode) it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a tag with a black background and use its *bgstipple* option to make a dot. Then apply this tag to your tab characters. In the example below, I use PIL to create the .xbm file for the stipple but you can also create it with some image edition software and replace `bgstipple="@stipple.xbm"` by `bgstipple="@/path/to/bitmap.xbm"`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

root = tk.Tk()
font = Font(root)
# create the bitmap for the stipple using the font character size
w, h = font.measure(" "), font.metrics("linespace")
stipple = Image.new("1", (w, h), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(stipple)
draw.ellipse((w//2 - 1, h//2 - 1, w//2 + 1, h//2 + 1), fill="white")
stipple.save("stipple.xbm")

text = tk.Text(root, font=font, tabs="4cm")
# configure tag for tabs
text.tag_configure("tab", background="black", bgstipple="@stipple.xbm")
text.insert("end", "Toy Car")
text.insert("end", "\t", "tab") # apply tag to tab
text.insert("end", "$10,00\n")
text.insert("end", "Toy Bear")
text.insert("end", "\t", "tab")
text.insert("end", "$5,00\n")

text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT**: As suggested by acw1668, one can use

```
 text = tk.Text(root, font=font, tabs="4.5cm right")
```

to align the prices to the right.

Comment: @ThomasIreland Then please accept my answer (click on the green tick below the answer's score)

Comment: Is it better to use `tabs="4.5c right"` to align the prices at the right?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, sure thanks for pointing that out. I was focusing more on showing the dots than on the text alignment.